# Getting text data with .getAttribute in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, input, getattribute

I'm trying to retrieve the text from a container/card text box on [this Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit). I basically want to retrieve the questions and related answers.

I can retrieve the questions using css code but I don't know how to get the answers. The answers are included, more or less, in this type of code:

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="on" tabindex="0" aria-label="valeur d'une option" value="Doctor's availability in hotel" dir="ltr" data-initial-value="Doctor's availability in hotel">
```

Here the answer is:

```
data-initial-value="Doctor's availability in hotel"
```

Here we want to get:

```
data-initial-value="Doctor's availability in hotel"
```

So, I tried the next one with `.get_attribute':

```
# I get all the letters with the questions and answers inside
containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "freebirdFormeditorViewItemContentWrapper"
)
questionnaire = {}
# for each card
for container in containers:
    try:
        question = container.find_element_by_css_selector(".exportTextarea[aria-label='Intitulé de la question']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("NoSuchElementException in " + container)
        continue
    # Get the answers
    responses = container.find_elements_by_class_name(
        "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
    )
    print("responses: ", responses)
    extracted_responses = [response.get_attribute("data-initial-value") for response in responses]

    questionnaire[question.text] = extracted_responses
```

But I don't get the answers:

```
responses:  []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
responses = container.find_element_by_css_selector(
  ".quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
)
```